# UISlider doesn't move smoothly while using side menu

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller, uislider, side-menu

I'm using a sidebar menu in Xamarin using the component Sidebar Navigation.

The problem that I have a UISlider inside UIScrollView inside a UIViewController that is content view controller. It contains a UISlider, the uislider works normally on simulater.

On physical device it doesn't work smoothly, I have to drag it from the very accurate center point which is quite annoying. When I try to view that UIViewController without using SidebarNavigation it works just fine as expected..
Any idea or Suggestion?

**-Update-**
-to Reproduce the problem you will also need to have the UISlider inside a UIScrollview
-link of a repository to demo the issue
[Xamarin-SideBarNavigation-UISlider-Issue-Demo](https://github.com/aproram/Xamarin-SideBarNavigation-UISlider-Issue-Demo)

Comment: Strange, I tried to reproduce your issue. But I feel it is smooth with device on my side. Could you please provide a sample project which can reproduce it?

Comment: @Kevin  
Something was missing yeah, you have to use the UISlider inside a UIScrollview.. Sorry for missing that. I have updated the post and I have made a repo that does reproduce the issue.